# Assign values from one model to another without checking null values each time

Tags: c#

I need to assign values from one model to another only if values aren't null.

How can I simplify the code below? What pattern should I use?

```
DatabaseModel databaseModel = new DatabaseModel();
databaseModel.DatabaseModelProperty1 = 1;
databaseModel.DatabaseModelProperty1 = 2;

ContractModel contractModel = new ContractModel();
contractModel.ContractProperty1 = 5;
contractModel.ContractProperty2 = new ContractModel.InnerContractModel_1();
contractModel.ContractProperty2.InnerContract_1Property1 = 10;

// each time I need to write if and check null values:
if (contractModel.ContractProperty1.HasValue)
{
    databaseModel.DatabaseModelProperty1 = contractModel.ContractProperty1.Value;
}

if (contractModel.ContractProperty2 != null)
{
    if (contractModel.ContractProperty2.InnerContract_1Property1.HasValue)
    {
        databaseModel.DatabaseModelProperty2 = contractModel.ContractProperty2.InnerContract_1Property1.Value;
    }

    if (contractModel.ContractProperty2.InnerContract_1Property2.HasValue)
    {
        databaseModel.DatabaseModelProperty3 = contractModel.ContractProperty2.InnerContract_1Property2.Value;
    }
}

// ..........
```

My first model:

```
public class DatabaseModel
{
    public int DatabaseModelProperty1 { get; set; }

    public int DatabaseModelProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int DatabaseModelProperty3 { get; set; }
    public int DatabaseModelProperty4 { get; set; }
    public int DatabaseModelProperty5 { get; set; }
}
```

My second model:

```
public class ContractModel
{
    public int? ContractProperty1 { get; set; }

    public InnerContractModel_1 ContractProperty2 { get; set; }

    public InnerContractModel_2 ContractProperty3 { get; set; }

    public class InnerContractModel_1
    {
        public int? InnerContract_1Property1 { get; set; }

        public int? InnerContract_1Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerContractModel_2
    {
        public int? InnerContract_2Property1 { get; set; }

        public int? InnerContract_2Property2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I don't want to check each time null values but I have no idea what I should change.

Comment: A little bit shorter: databaseModel.DatabaseModelProperty1 = contractModel.ContractProperty1.HasValue ? contractModel.ContractProperty1.Value : 1; And for the path where sth else can be null like this (with "?"): contractModel.ContractProperty2?.InnerContract_1Property1.HasValue == true

Comment: You can probably [use AutoMapper](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/58354104/how-to-configure-automapper-9-to-ignore-object-properties-if-object-is-null-but-map-if-not-null) for this.